# Get pending Facebook group posts via GraphAPI as group admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am an admin of a Facebook group. When I checked last time a few months ago, Facebook's GraphAPI would return all posts, incl. those that were still pending approval, when I queried the feed of the group.

However, when I checked yesterday, posts still pending approval did not show up anymore (although I couldn't find any information about this change in the API change log).

Is there any way to retrieve the pending posts? I do not even need to know if they are pending or approved, it would be sufficient to get all posts via the API.